# How to quickly delete files and folders in Windows 10 so that they can never be recovered or accessed again

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, formatting, secure-erase, eraser

I have an application and txt files where the records of this application are kept. When I give a command via `CMD`, I want these files to be quickly deleted, irrecoverable and inaccessible. Depending on the situation, the files can be deleted first and then the deleted files can be cleaned. Or the entire ssd can be deleted.

In fact, exactly what I want is to delete the data as quickly as possible with the command given via `CMD`.

I used `SDelete` but it is very slow and I can still access some txt files.

I used `Optimize-Volume` but I'm not sure it cleans up.

I used `Eraser` but it takes too long.

If I use `bitlocker` as a last resort, can I at least make the data inaccessible? Thanks.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen How can i do this?

Comment: what type of drive? an ssd you could just quick format.

Comment: 4TB m2 ssd. The only ssd on which windows is also installed.